# Snake_case or camelCase in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have **node.js** application that exposes some **API** to clients and connects to some **SQL** database.
First let introduce some premises:

1. Clients must use API with **snake_case** (keys in JSON object sent in request body are in snake_case).
2. Database column names are also **snake_case**.

Problem is because **javascript** standard/practice is using **camelCase** which I would like to keep.

So as I see there are 3 solutions:

1. Transform data from snake(API) to camel (application) to snake (database) on the fly as needed.
   This would introduced some new layers to system and all of it would be little complicated than other solutions.
2. Use snake_case in node.js app.
   But no matter if I use snake all other dependencies I am using will still be in camel which doesn't solve whole problem.
3. Mix snake_case and camelCase in node.js app. This is something I would like to avoid :)

So what do you suggest? Mine favorite is first solutions but if you have some other smart ideas not mentioned here please feel free to tell.

Comment: Npm is your friend: check [to-snake-case](https://npmjs.org/package/to-snake-case) and [to-camel-case](https://npmjs.org/package/to-camel-case) modules.

Answer (score 16):

As [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) principle says, the simplest solution is the best one.

If you have client's requirements on the one hand and [node.js code style guides](https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide) on the other hand. I would take the simplest solution satisfying the both. External API should be snake case and internally you can use camel case. If you stick to consistency you can use snake case everywhere, as I assume client's requirements have higher priority.

I would really avoid any additional layers for converting cases as it introduces additional complexity to the final solution, it can have additional errors, and it will require additional maintenance in the future.

Answer (score 11):

Personally, when I have to deal with snake case in javascript, I use it only with square brackets:

```
data['user_id'] = 1;
```

so, technically I don't violate any style rules: these are just strings, not identifiers

Answer (score 10):

> Problem is because javascript standard/practice is using camelCase which I would like to keep.

There is no such standard practice. It depends on a style. Node.js itself uses camel case, we internally stick with a snake case because it's more readable. Do as you like.

But if your API uses snake case, it's very good reason to stick with snake case yourself. So I suggest to stick with option 2.

Option 1 is out of the question imho, because using the SAME identifier in different styles is prone to errors. Option 3 is kinda acceptable.

Comment: Apparently, [snake_case is easier to read](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~jmaletic/papers/ICPC2010-CamelCaseUnderScoreClouds.pdf). At least, for me.

Comment: donut, That study used programmers who were trained in snake case as subjects. So their conclusion that snake case "is easier to read" is flawed. I'd like to see a comparable study on subjects trained in camelCase.

Comment: I used to be a diehard `camelCaseFool` in C++. After a while with Python I realized how beautiful and readable `snake_case` is. It's way, WAY more readable. I only use `PascalCase` for classes. Every variable is snake case. And you're right, I use snake case in Javascript too. Screw the "node.js style guide". They can use whatever they want internally. So will I. I'll use what is more readable. I am not responsible for their bad choices. Besides, the only reason Node uses camelcase is because Javascript's own default API (from the 1990s) uses it. Snake helps differentiate our code from APIs!

Comment: @DavidSpector What are you talking about? "That study used programmers who were trained in snake case"? **NO! READ the study!** Quote from study, they looked at both styles and quote another study on camelCase: `The subjects (who had programming experience) were mostly trained in the camel-case style.` which found that general subjects overall read the snake case style 13.5% faster. This new study ALSO used both types of programmers: `All of our subjects had experience with both styles and their preferences of style was approximately split even among the group.` So, `tunnel_snake_case_rules`!

Comment: You can and should read the study and look at the graphs. The eye tracker showed that the eyes spend a ton of time `tryingToParseCamelCaseToUnderstandIt`. Meanwhile `snake_case_is_instantly_understandable`. It's pretty logical, really, regardless of what your personal preference is. Oneisliterallyafreakingrunonsentencewithoutbreaks. The other is spaced out like normal writing. It's not even a contest. It's not even strange at all that snake case is better.

Comment: @MitchMcMabers note that the first quote from the study is a comment on a second study; the full context is "`To address this topic, Binkley at [sic] al... conducted a study with 135 subjects... [who] were mostly trained in the camel-case style.`" The context for your second quote: "`Here, we attempt to replicate Binkley et al.’s [4] experiment... [where all] of our subjects had experience with both styles... In addition,` **most of the subjects were historically trained in the underscore style.**" Not a comment on snake vs camel case, purely informative for future users :)